# Wordpress Custom CSS added twice?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

Not 100% sure if this question is legit for stack, but it doesn't belong in Meta and it does involve some code, and I don't think its subjective - should have an answer...

I have a new wordpress site using The7 theme and I have, of course, created a child theme using "One Click Child Theme" plugin.

All works fine, I put a little custom css in there to adjust the navigation and it adjusts, but when I look at the Inspector in chrome, I see my custom css listed twice!  Does anyone know why this is?  I don't have any extra `import` statements in my child stylesheet, and even if I did, this code isn't in the parent stylesheet anyhow.  Is the child stylesheet being loaded twice?

I know quite a bit of web code, but fairly new to using Wordpress.  Is this normal behavior?

This is my entire child stylesheet:

```
/*
Theme Name:     the7 Child
Description:    
Author:         chris@sqlfocus.com
Template:       dt-the7

(optional values you can add: Theme URI, Author URI, Version, License, License URI, Tags, Text Domain)
*/

ul.main-nav {
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;   
    -webkit-padding-start: 100px;
    -webkit-padding-end: 100px;
}
```

This is the inspector:
[image]

functions.php:

```
<?php
//
// Recommended way to include parent theme styles.
//  (Please see http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#How_to_Create_a_Child_Theme)
//  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array('parent-style')
    );
}
//
// Your code goes below
//
```

Comment: what do you mean listed twice? In the rendered rules or you see the css link twice?

Comment: updated question with image of my inspector

Comment: Share the code from your `functions.php` file, where you enqueue the stylesheet for the Child Theme

Comment: Shared.  Looks like it only loads once.

Comment: [crickets]  I can't believe this is beyond the knowledge of everyone on SO

Comment: The anwer is here, fix functions.php code: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167639/why-does-my-child-theme-css-get-called-twice

Comment: I switched themes a while ago and don't have the same problem anymore.  For some reason with the old theme, the "One-Click Child Theme" plugin, did not properly edit the functions php with the correct path to the parent stylesheet.  If you look at my functions.php code above, you can see it used the same path as the child stylesheet.  Not sure why that happened but it didn't happen using X theme.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with an Enfold theme and I've seen it before with other themes.

I studied the HTML output for a page and discovered the theme was auto-including my stylesheet. This is unexpected and therefore undesirable because unpredictability is undesirable -- not all themes do this.

The fix? Kinda funny... but I just...

`removed my own reference from functions.php and let the parent theme auto-include it for me`

Sad but true...